# Is this considered grammar?

Tags: grammaticality, articles

If I say "today was good day," and add an *a* in the right spot like, "today was *a* good day," from a broad view, is what I just did considered a *grammatical* change or something else?

Comment: The first one is wrong and the second right. What are you asking? What to call the process of taking an utterance with wrong grammar and fixing it? How about 'fixing bad grammar'?

Comment: ...which is to say 'grammatical change' isn't really a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, although ***change*** is perhaps not the word you want. In the second sentence, with *a*, the phrase *a good day* is a Predicate Noun Phrase -- i.e, although the official verb is *was*, the meaningful predication part is *a good day*. Nothing has been changed here; the first sentence doesn't exist as a source. But there *is* a distinction to be made, and it depends on what kind of predicate the sentence has.

Verbs are the prototype predicates, and English requires a tensed verb in every finite clause to be marked for tense; but there are other kinds of predicates, like Predicate Adjectives:

- *She is tired.*
- *He is very tall*.

which require some form of *be*.

Predicate NPs (Predicate Nouns for short) also require some form of *be*, but in addition, if they're count nouns, they are marked by an indefinite article, *a*. That's why your first sentence is wrong: it's ungrammatical to use a predicate count noun without *a*, just as it would be to use it without *be*. But it's equally ungrammatical to use *a* with a predicate adjective. (Ungrammatical sentences are marked with an asterisk *)

**Predicate Adjectives:**

- **Today very hot*
- **Today a very hot*
- *Today was very hot.*
- **Today was a very hot*

**Predicate Nouns:**

- **Today good day*
- **Today a good day*
- **Today was good day*
- *Today was a good day.*

Comment: I don't think the predicate nature of the noun has anything to do with it, does it John? The same problem would exist if the noun were functioning as a subject.

Comment: I'm going to interpret *the first sentence doesn't exist as a source* as your way of saying *the first series of words isn't a grammatical sentence*. In which case I might have wanted to say that inserting "a" into the series "grammaticalises" it into a sentence. But I think that word has already been co-opted for a different meaning, so IMHO the "change" can only really be called a "correction".

Comment: I agree, FF. It's often hard answering questions as they are presented because they're so often odd mixtures of ideas about how language works.

Comment: @Brett, the predicate nature of the noun is where the obligatory _a_ comes from. I suspect -- though they did not say so -- that the original poster is a native speaker of a language like Chinese or Malay that simply puts subject and predicate non-verbs together without benefit of _be_. 
It's very hard for people who've never felt a need for such a thing to figure out just where English wants it, where it doesn't want it, and where it doesn't care.

Comment: I still don't follow. *good day is coming* would be just as ungrammatical.

Comment: Agreed. But for a different reason. 
_A good day is coming_ requires a referential indefinite article in order for the NP to have any reference at all. 
The indefinite article in _She's a doctor_, however, is **not** referential. _She_ is not being identified with some other _doctor_; rather, Doctorhood is being predicated of _her_. 
In short, _doctor_ is the real predicate; _be_ and _a_ are cogs in the construction, and don't have anything to do with the normal, referential, use of indefinite articles.

Comment: OK, the article has a different purpose in both situations, but is that relevant to the question? Wouldn't it be more useful to make the general statement that singular count nouns typically require a determiner?

Comment: But that's circular. You can tell count nouns because they can take an indefinite article; mass nouns can't. If you can't tell mass nouns from count nouns without using an article, saying that all count nouns require articles is not a helpful rule to tell anybody. As for what's relevant to the original question, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: I see what you mean, but a competent dictionary user should usually be able to tell count from non-count nouns. Your formulation of the rule makes no distinction and just says any noun requires an article. How then do you deal with the count/non-count issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1924/discussion-between-john-m-lawler-and-brett-reynolds)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a grammatical change. It's not a spelling change, a punctuation change, or a vocabulary change.

Comment: It's only a grammatical change in the sense that *without* "a", the sentence isn't grammatical in the first place.

Comment: Indeed, quite so.